# Load node based on a field name

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have a content type that has a unique field.  How can I load a specific node based on this?  `node_load()` only takes the `nid`.  I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed an API function: [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7), which has lots of example use cases [scattered around this site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=entityfieldquery).

Answer (score 2):

Run a query against the database to find the node that has the field with the specified value and return the nid.  Then run the nid through `node_load()`

Comment: Thanks, was just wondering if there was an API for that.